How to find HTML element based on split up text in children
The element I am trying to find has a hashed classId so the easiest way I know how to find it is either by text or using cy.focused(). Unfortunately, I need to unfocus it and focus it again, but the element gets remounted in the process so I can't use a .focused() result from earlier. This leads me to trying to do something like this:
cy.contains('abcdefgh').click();

where 'abcdefgh' is a dynamic string.
but this cant find the element that has dynamic text split up like this:
<div class="kj45k4h535Hashed">
  <div class="input-text">
    <div>ab</div>
    <div>cd</div>
    <div>ef</div>
    <div>gh</div>
  </div>
</div>

Where I think its split after a certain length but haven't counted yet. Is there a way I can find an element by text that is split up after an unknown number of characters?
EDIT: showed which element has hashed className for clarity

consult the textContent of the outer div, which ignores tags, but note that you may need to do a string replace to get rid of white space (because those tags may have introduced newlines and/or spaces)

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans good to know. I guess I would still need to traverse all .input-texts to find the one with that text content but that seems possible

This is even more confusing now - 1) which element are you trying to click? 2) Why can't you just inspect the DOM to see what way the text is split? Please add more realistic examples - please show two variants of the text split so we can understand the problem.

@Billy.Burr 1) Any of them. 2) Bc I think it may be auto split due to the window size

One approach is to run a sequence of traversal commands that follows the HTML structure.
For your sample HTML this would be
cy.contains('div', 'ab')      // this specifies the child that owns the text
  .siblings(':contains(cd)')  // next child
  .siblings(':contains(ef)')  // etc
  .siblings(':contains(gh)')
  .parent()                   // presuming this is what you want to click
  .should('have.class', 'input-text') 


I added the final assertion to prove the final subject is the parent div, but of course your actual class is hashed so you can't use an assertion.
Ref :contains() pseudo selector

Exact text
One issue is the :contains() selector performs a partial match and may give you the wrong elements.
You can roll your own pseudos, here is one I use for exact text
Top of test or in /cypress/support/e2e.js
const {$} = Cypress
$.expr.pseudos.textEquals = Cypress.$.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function( elem ) {
    /* strip arg leading and trailing dbl quote */ 
    const expected = arg.replace(/^"/, '').replace(/"$/, '')
    return $(elem).text() === expected
  }
})

cy.contains('div', 'ab')
  .siblings(':textEquals(cd)')
  .siblings(':textEquals(ef)')
  .siblings(':textEquals(gh)')
  .parent()
  .should('have.class', 'input-text')


When some of the text parts are repeated elsewhere
The test above fails when there is another block of HTML that repeats only some of the text parts, for example if this block precedes the one you want to find:
<div class="input-text">
  <div>ab</div>          // matched
  <div>cd</div>          // matched
  <div>kl</div>          // fails on .siblings(':contains(ef)')
  <div>mn</div>
</div>


To build a more specific selector, add in the :has() pseudo selector.
You could build it like this
const textParts = ['ab','cd','ef','gh']
const selectorParts = textParts.map(part => `:has(div:contains(${part}))`)
const selector = `div${selectorParts.join('')}`
cy.get(selector)
  .should('have.class', 'input-text')

Now the query skips the div.input that only partially matches the child texts.


Unknown text split
I would prefer to test with a reproducible split up of the text, say by setting the viewport.
If that's not possible, you can try using the .children() command to extract the text.
cy.get('div.input-text')
  .children()
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', 'abcdefgh') 

If there are other similar div.input-text on the page that you want to ignore, you can scan them all and set an alias to the matching one.
cy.get('div.input-text')
  .each($el => {
    const text = $el.children().text()
    if (text === 'abcdefgh') {
      cy.wrap($el).as('target')     // remember this one
    }
  })

cy.get('@target')
  .children()
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', 'abcdefgh')



Thank you for the detailed answer. If I knew exactly how the text would be split into divs this would work perfectly for me. I edited my question to be more clear that I'm not sure how the text will split up

Since (you suppose) the break-up of the text depends on window width, you should try setting cy.viewport() so that the DOM becomes predictable.

The default window in a Cypress test size is 1000 x 660, it should yield the same split each time you run the test.
